# How to read data from java properties file using Spring Boot

Tags: java, properties, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application and I want to read some variable from my `application.properties` file. In fact below codes do that. But I think there is a good method for this alternative.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;

try {
    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    prop.load(input);
    gMapReportUrl = prop.getProperty("gMapReportUrl");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `@PropertySource` to externalize your configuration to a properties file. There is number of way to do get properties:

**1.
Assign the property values to fields by using `@Value` with `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` to resolve `${}` in `@Value`:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:config.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Value("${gMapReportUrl}")
    private String gMapReportUrl;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

**2.
Get the property values by using `Environment`:**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:config.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public void foo() {
        env.getProperty("gMapReportUrl");
    }

}
```

Hope this can help

Comment: Why foo void? How to use this class?

Comment: @gstackoverflow It is just an example. You can use it as you like.

Comment: getting FileNotfoundException, but my file is in the resources folder res/sensitive.properties

Comment: @PropertySource() is optional. Just in case anyone needs this information

Answer (score 16):

I have created following class

### ConfigUtility.java

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigUtility {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String getProperty(String pPropertyKey) {
        return env.getProperty(pPropertyKey);
    }
}
```

and called as follow to get application.properties value

### myclass.java

```
@Autowired
private ConfigUtility configUtil;

public AppResponse getDetails() {

  AppResponse response = new AppResponse();
    String email = configUtil.getProperty("emailid");
    return response;        
}
```

### application.properties

emailid=sunny@domain.com

unit tested, working as expected...

Comment: I notice you don't specify a property file name? Does this just load all *.properties files in the classpath?

Answer (score 15):

i would suggest the following way:

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:otherprops.properties")
@Controller
public class ClassA {
    @Value("${myName}")
    private String name;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/xyz")
    @ResponseBody
    public void getName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Here your new properties file name is "otherprops.properties" and the property name is "myName". This is the simplest implementation to access properties file in spring boot version 1.5.8.

Comment: I have "sensitive.properties" inside the resources folder, have used the above approach with @Configuration annotation, but it is not able to read value.

Comment: @Girish please check the location of your properties file. In the above approach, the properties file was in the same location with the application.properties file

Comment: I also have it in the resources folder, but Environment is null and propertysource also not working

Comment: @Girish this should work actually. please check typographical errors.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want to expose every property from either a .properties or .yml file, Spring Boot automatically creates an endpoint that does just that: endpoint `/actuator/env`. It is disabled by default though.
To enable it, be sure to include `env` in the application property below:
`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env`

You can then filter the properties that you want to keep in the program that reads the endpoint.