# How to change Spring Boot properties default path in Tomcat development environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I need to use two `*.properties` file to determine config of Spring Boot application server. How can I set the second configuration path?

I use `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.5.10` and such `*.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.url=url
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialec
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=
org.springframewok.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=30000
```

Now, I need to address database info from another properties file.

Edit: Note that I need to put second properties file outside of my WAR file in `WEB-INF` folder.

Answer (score 1):

**(1)** This is best practices when switching between development mode and production environment.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles

Reference for version `1.5.10.RELEASE`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

For more specific, you create 3 files

`application.properties` for common properties.

`application-dev.properties` for only own properties what used in profile `dev`

`application-production.properties` for only own properties what used in profile `production`

(Notice: Has convention over naming)

Point profile what used, in `application.properties` has line `spring.profiles.active=dev` (in development) or `spring.profiles.active=production` (in production)

**(2)**

> Note that I need to put second properties file outside of my WAR file
>   in WEB-INF folder.

Assumption, your file is `foo.properties`. It is outside WAR file, **it has not nature of Spring's properties file**. Therefore, Spring Framework/Spring Boot can not read it automatically. You must write few lines of Java code to reading the content of `foo.properties`, then assign to configuration manually (see example [configuration class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html#boot-features-profiles))

Comment: I just edit my question, please make me advice based on that note

Comment: Bear in mind: File `*.properties` outsite WAR file, it is not Spring's properties.

Comment: Ok man, Thanks I got it. now I should search how to set properties from code

Comment: Consider using `spring.config.location` (an alternative for config by Java code) Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Answer (score 0):

You can access multiple of properties file using `@PropertySource`

Follow the following stackoverflow thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178674/7538821