# Reading own properties file with Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

How can I use my own .properties file with spring-boot. I don't want to use the application.properties. I have to exclude some properties from there. Are there any annotations for that?

Comment: If I am correctly understanding your question, you can use @PropertySource for custom properties file.

Comment: See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) for more information on `@PropertySource`

Comment: thanks it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:yourproperties.properties")`

you can follow this stackoverflow thread
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178674/7538821

Answer (score 0):

```
@PropertySource("classpath:custom.properties")
```

on your class and i suggest the .yml file instead of properties which will give you more flexibility