# Null pointer using @Autowire Environment inside a @Component on a sub-package

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple `Spring Boot` project with the following directory structure:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       ├── example
│   │   │       │   └── base
.   .   │       │       ├── db
.   .   │       │       │   ├── entity
.   .   │       │       │   │   └── SomeComponent.java
.   .   │       │       │   ├── repository
        │       │       │   └── util
        │       │       └── development
        │       └── MainApplication.java     
        └── resources
            └── application.properties
```

The `MainApplication` is basically the default one:

```
package com.example.base;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
    ...
```

In MainApplication.java I actually got a valid reverence to the environment and I can actually access it properly, however I'm getting **null** in SomeComponent.class

```
package com.example.base.db.entity;

@Component
public class SomeComponent {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public SomeComponent() {}

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(env);
    }

}
```

This is supposed to work fine because SomeComponent.java is in a sub package of **com.example.base** which should be scanned automatically by the default configuration of `@SpringBootApplication` right ? I don't see why this is failing.

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, I found myself the issue, I was instantiating my component using new (as a rookie mistake). I added the following Bean to my MainApplication.class and everything started flowing.

```
@Bean
public SomeComponent someComponent() {
    return new SomeComponent();
}
```

And when I need it I just use context.getBean(SomeComponent.class)

Comment: `Spring Boot` made some things simpler than `spring mvc`

Answer (score 0):

`Spring Boot` has simplified this process. You can access values from properties file with the following codes:

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "classpath:otherprops.properties")
@Controller
public class ClassA {
    @Value("${myName}")
    private String name;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/xyz")
    @ResponseBody
    public void getName(){
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47178674/7538821) for more reference.