# Need to get path to a folder in resources

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

I am using Spring boot application. I have this structure in my resource folder

```
resources
 |__customers
      |__retail
```

I have to pass the path to this folder to one of the beans for writing files.
The names of the files are dynamic so I cannot pass a predefined value to the file.

To do this I tried

```
@value(${classpath:resources/customer/retail} )
Resources resource;

// Also tried 
ResourceLoader loader = new FileSystemResourceLoader();

ResourceUtils.getURL(filePathDump).getPath().getClass().getResource(
    "indexingData/publication/analysis/dump"
);
// and several other options
```

but it shows throw file not found or resource not found Exception, Now I checked the way path are defined for each one of them and I am positive they were all specified correctly

I need a way to pass this path to a folder in resources. Please help

Comment: Did you tried `ClassPathResource `?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read data from java properties file using Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281512/how-to-read-data-from-java-properties-file-using-spring-boot)

Comment: @Samim I find this not related at all completely different requirement.

Comment: @Lucie Kinldy review your code as the `resource` variable is nowhere used. Further `@Value` annotation is not used correctly.

Comment: @Samim I wanted to mention that I used values, I am using a xml file version but the issue is consistent

Comment: @soorapadman I tried using `ClassPathResource` but no use, didnt solve this isssue

Comment: @Lucie may i know how you have done please ?

Comment: If you dont have path create it . while writing the path to the file .

Comment: Even If I create it how would I pass resource folder path

Answer (score 1):

you can autowire `org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader` and then get file as follows:

```
resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:customer/retail/someFile.txt")
```

Comment: As I have mentioned in the I have a dynamic file name So I need the path to the folder to append my file name on the fly.

Comment: If you want the path then use `Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).toURI());`

Comment: @Lucie you can do it on the fly. I suppose you have a service method where you are working with the files, so there you can invoke this `resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:folderNameInResource/" + fileName)` ... or I must have got you question wrong

Comment: @Samim It returns null

Comment: @Adrian I am using Paths.write() to write I file, Would I wont be able to use this path to write a file