# Maven Profiles - How do i get the values assigned to properties in the .properties file and assign them to variables in my class?

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-profiles

really need some help here because I cannot seem to figure this out.

I have followed **Maven Profiles – Example 2** in the following guide https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-profiles-example/

Here is my pom.xml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- necessary for intellij to function -->
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>testAPI.automation.java</artifactId>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <env>test</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>integration</id>
        <properties>
            <env>integration</env>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    </profiles>

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.exparity</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-date</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <!-- Loading all ${} -->
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/env/config.${env}.properties</filter>
        </filters>

        <!-- Map ${} into resources -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- display active profile in compile phase -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-help-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>show-profiles</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>active-profiles</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Here are my properties files. I am only using two env configs at the moment 'test' and 'integration'**
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Here is my BaseTest class. Previously I was getting the URL values directly from the pom.xml file and assigning them to variables for use in my tests. How do I now access the values stored in the config files so I can assign them to variables for use in my tests?**

[image]

**When I debug, all I get are nulls. Running *'mvn package -P integration'* in the terminal does not work either**

[image]

**However, it does say that the profile I specified is active when I execute 'mvn package -P integration'**

[image]

**In summary, what I am trying to achieve is to access the values stored in the config files so I can assign them to variables for use in my tests. Maybe I have misunderstood it. I am pretty new to Maven and Java and any help would be greatly appreciated**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

`System.getProperty` is not used to retrieve values from the user-defined file. You need to load properties manually, something like the following:

```java
public class BaseTest {

    String BaseUrl;

    public BaseTest() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        try (InputStream resourceAsStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties")) {
            prop.load(resourceAsStream);
            BaseUrl = (String) prop.get("url.baseUrl");
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please refer
[How to read data from java properties file using Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281512/how-to-read-data-from-java-properties-file-using-spring-boot)

The code you have written will only read values from environment variables.

Comment: I am not using Spring Boot. I am using JUnit. This is an API test solution.