# value from property file is null in spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, placeholder

I try to get value from property file in class path in spring,but returns null:
first,I have a property file named `person.properties` under the package of `v4.c3.property` with content:

```
name=tom
```

Then I have a config class:

```
package v4.c3.property;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Conditional;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public
    static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

And a test class:

```
package v4.c3.property;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Config.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:/v4/c3/property/person.properties")
public class Test {
    
    @Autowired
    Environment env;
    
    @org.junit.Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("The name is:"+env.getProperty("name"));
    }
}
```

and the `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>sia</groupId>
  <artifactId>sia</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run the test method, I got a result null:

```
The name is:null
```

Why it is null? How to get value from property file?

Comment: Is it going to use source resources or test resources ?

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38281734/9192223

Comment: Don't put `@PropertySource` on a test class that belongs on an `@Configuration` class.

Comment: @user3145373ツ java files and `person.properties` are in the source folder(the package v4.c3.property),I do not create any source resources folder or test resources folder

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right,I put it on the Config class,then I get the result I want